# Why can't my Node.js application find a module?

Tags: javascript, node-modules, package.json

I'm trying to start my app but every time I try `npm run dev` I get an error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\myname\Desktop\mern\index.js'
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

I don't remember this ever happening in the past so I'm at a lost for words. I tried deleting node_modules / package.json & re-installing them but that didn't work. Here is my code:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mern",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13"
  }
}
```

I think the problem has to be here in the package.json file but this is how i've always written it so I'm not sure what to do. Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just search your project for C:\Users\myname\Desktop\mern\index.js using find all. It will show you where the problem is.

Comment: @Trouble how do I use find all?/ where is it?

Comment: which code editor are you using ? For Visual Studio Code it is Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: @Trouble well that didn't work.. When i typed it in nothing popped up

Comment: Do you have index.js in your project ?  "main": "index.js", it is looking for index.js file to start your project. Either change it to some starting file like app.js or something or create a file index.js in src of your project.

Comment: @Trouble figured it out, just posted the answer, it was a simple misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had both the src and index.js in a server file. In the package.json file I both the `src/index.js` to `server/src/index.js`

Comment: Great Effort Bro..!